# Short story about psychic kids that end the world

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is driving me crazy and I can't seem to locate the author or title but I read this in an anthology and would like to read it again.

Three young children, 2 boys and a girl, become super-intelligent psychics that kill off the rest of the world because they are a threat. The girl decides they should mate in order to preserve their powers only to discover the baby she is carrying is more powerful than any of them (it speaks to her in utero) and will probably kill them off once it is born.

Most of the story, IIRC, centers on the 3 children and how 1 of them doesn't like that the little girl killed all the adults (and everyone else) because he misses his mum and dad.

Comment: Hmm.. quite some time ago -perhaps 5 years or more. I thought perhaps it was Asimov or Bradbury but I can't find anything like this tale among their bibliography. I DO know it was a short story, but I have no idea when it was written (I only have a feeling it's not a really modern tale but I'm not sure).

Comment: From just reading the title of the question, I thought the answer was going to be _Childhood's End_, but obviously it's not.

Answer (score 9):

I found the story - it was 'We Three' by Dean R. Koontz, 1974, which appears in *[Strange Highways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_Highways_(story_collection))* anthology. 
(I am the OP but I forgot my login info)

> "We Three": three siblings with special powers eliminate the rest of mankind, thinking that they're the "new race", but soon one of them is pregnant with a creature even more powerful who just might eliminate them.

Comment: You should be able to merge the accounts. There's information at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18233/278074 about the process. Account recovery, for finding the login info, is at http://stackoverflow.com/help/reset-password.

Comment: "We Three" originally appeared in "Final Stage: The Ultimate Science Fiction Anthology," which also contained Asimov's "That Thou Art Mindful of Him".

Answer (score 2):

This sounds a lot like "[Baby is Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_Is_Three)" By Theodore Sturgeon.

It was expanded to a full novel called "[More than Human](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_Than_Human)."

Comment: Nope lol not that one. Most of the story, iirc, centers on the 3 children and how 1 of them doesn't like that the little girl killed all the adults (and everyone else) because he misses his mum and dad.

Comment: What elements of Baby is Three correspond to the question?