# Short story in which three child siblings with superpowers kill all of humanity but are afraid of being destroyed in turn by their descendants

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, post-apocalyptic

The story begins with the three children (two females, one male), about ten years old, carrying the corpses of their parents to the back yard. Later you discover that they have exterminated all of humanity and that they have the power to kill any living being just by mentally desiring it. That is not their only power: they are also pyrokinetics and telepaths.

They have sex with each other and one of the sisters gets pregnant. They discover that soon the fetus is conscious and has mental powers superior to those of the parents. The story ends with one of the children expressing his fear of their descendant.

I'm not sure of the date of the tale, but I suppose it's about 1965-1970.

Comment: The other question doesn't have an accepted answer so we can't be sure if the answer to the other question is correct (though it seems very likely it is). Just accept your answer to this question. I think you may have to wait a while before accepting your own answer.

Comment: @JohnRennie The other answer has an accepted answer in the form of a second account by the OP which is fine by our standards. The only reason I haven't VTC'd yet is because it's unclear if it is actually the OP or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer in this question: [Short story about psychic kids that end the world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90527/short-story-about-psychic-kids-that-end-the-world?rq=1)

The story I was looking for was "We Three" (1974) by Dean R. Koontz, which appears in the *[Strange Highways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_Highways_(story_collection))* anthology.

> "We Three": three siblings with special powers eliminate the rest of mankind, thinking that they're the "new race", but soon one of them is pregnant with a creature even more powerful who just might eliminate them.

Comment: I've edited this just to include the answer so it's clearer what it is.